# Is it possible for me to run two python processes at once, one using the coral tpu, and another using only the cpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tpu, google-coral

For example if I wanted to run a lane detection algorithm, and an object detection algorithm at simulataneously.

Comment: "Is it possible..." is not a programming question. Try implementing a solution, and when you get stuck, come back here and ask a specific, detailed question.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and it is very open ended. Kindly add more infos on actually what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Running two or more simultaneous python processes is possible but only one model can be executed on the TPU at once. When multiple models are too slow to run on a single Edge TPU, they needs to be executed across multiple Edge TPUs, so plugging the USB Accelerator into the DevBoard is a good test environment for that method.

One model can be loaded to the Dev Board and other one to the USB Accelerator. Please check this out : https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/multiple-edgetpu/